# Google Interactive Charts not loading when UpdatePanel is refreshed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, google-visualization

Help! I've spent hours researching this and can't find a solution. I'm using the Google Interactive Charts API in an UpdatePanel which asynchronously refreshes when I change the selection in a dropdownlist, which ultimately changes the data set for the Google chart. The problem is that the chart disappears when the UpdatePanel refreshes. I am using RegisterStartupScript and I have tested a javascript alert in the updatepanel to confirm that javascript works in the UpdatePanel when it refreshes, so the problem seems confined to whatever the Google javascript is doing. Perhaps it's the setOnLoadCallback not actually calling drawChart after UpdatePanel is refreshed? Not sure if that's it or how to fix it.

The code below is in a Public Sub which is called on Page_Load and when the dropdownlist's selected value is changed.

```
    Dim strOutput As New StringBuilder

    strOutput.Append("google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });")
    strOutput.Append("google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);")
    strOutput.Append("function drawChart() {")
    strOutput.Append("var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();")
    strOutput.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'Domain');")
    strOutput.Append("data.addColumn('number', 'Value');")
    strOutput.Append("data.addRows([")

    Dim sqlSelect As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    sqlSelect.CommandText = String.Format("spAnalytics_ViewsByDomain")
    sqlSelect.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Dim dtChartData As DataTable = clsDB.FillDT(sqlSelect)

    Dim commaCounter As Integer = 1
    For Each row As DataRow In dtChartData.Rows
        If ddlStat.SelectedValue = "hits" Then
            strOutput.Append(String.Format("['{0}',{1}]", row.Item("domain"), row.Item("hit_count")))
        ElseIf ddlStat.SelectedValue = "sessions" Then
            strOutput.Append(String.Format("['{0}',{1}]", row.Item("domain"), row.Item("session_count")))
        End If
        If commaCounter <> dtChartData.Rows.Count Then strOutput.Append(",")
        commaCounter = commaCounter + 1
    Next

    strOutput.Append("]);")

    strOutput.Append("var options = { 'title': 'Views by domain',")
    strOutput.Append("'width': 500,")
    strOutput.Append("'height': 300")
    strOutput.Append("};")
    strOutput.Append("var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));")
    strOutput.Append("chart.draw(data, options);")
    strOutput.Append("}")

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(litDomains, GetType(String), "blahblah", strOutput.ToString, True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leave out the google.setOnloadCallback and just add a call to the function directly at the end.

Comment: I feel like that got me closer, but it still doesn't load the chart. 

I added strOutput.append("drawChart();") and removed the google.setOnloadCallback line. The chart loads when the page loads, but when the updatePanel refreshes, the chart disappears, though now the height of the original chart remains, whereas before it disappeared.

Comment: There are just too many things that could affect this. Is 'chart_div' being replaced in the updatepanel too? Are you getting a javascript error? Is the 'data' variable showing the correct data in your browser's JS debugger?

Comment: chart_div is being replaced in the updatePanel too. If I move it outside the update panel, it won't change when the javascript is updated in the updatePanel. Not getting any javascript errors. Not sure how to check the data variable, do I do that through Firebug? I know the data is correct because it works if I remove the updatePanel, just don't want the page postback and I know a lot of folks have been looking for a solution to this. BTW, I actually had to include google.setOnloadCallback because it won't load without it (was inheriting from another chart, removed all others to help deduce).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with Firefox only. the chart *did* redraw properly in Chrome, IE, and Safari. I found a solution but it's what I would call a kludge. However, I am satisfied and it works.

I did some browser detection and for only Firefox I added a **setTimeout** of 10ms around the call to redraw the code.

The only other solution that I had read about was to replace the UpdatePanel with JS AJAX and I found this solution preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar issue using google charts with update panel, hence posting the solution.

Javascript code breaks after asynchronous or partial refresh by update panel. Please refer following article to understand cause and solution: [Update panel and jQuery issue](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-Plugins-not-working-after-ASPNet-AJAX-UpdatePanel-Partial-PostBack-or-when-Asynchronous-request-is-over.aspx).

To fix the issue regarding partial refresh, just add the following code in addition to your code to re-apply javascript code. This code calls the function to draw the chart like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
        if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
            //Event Raised when the Async Postback is completed.
        }

        // Your function which draws chart
        drawChart();

    });

</script>
```